# Http error when playing video by flash player

Tags: http, browser, cross-browser, flash

I write this http file, but i have a issue. I can play video by http5, but can't play by flash player.

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<h1>Видеоплеер</h1>
<p>Файл: kinopoisk2013.mp4</p>

<video width="800" height="600" poster="kinopoisk2013.png" controls='controls'>
    <source src="kinopoisk2013.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object>
      <embed src=kinopoisk2013.mp4" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" />
    </object>
    <p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает <code>video</code> элемент.</p>  
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot directly play MP4 videos using embed tag and flash like we can do using HTML5 video tag. You need to use a Flash player like ["Flowplayer"](http://flowplayer.org/)

Comment: @Denis I don't think that is a working code sample, if you have a look  at the [Plug-ins and ActiveX elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/hh920753(v=vs.85).aspx) document it shows the usage of a flash player